# "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value...." How to Fix Code in .cs file

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#

I'm getting this error on my .Cs Log file. cant understand why this showing now. 
the error says its in Line 43[image]

Another issue is that this code sometimes for this project is that it logs in fine sometimes, sometimes its giving the above error. 
Here is my **LogApplication.cs** code.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;using System.Data;

namespace YCT.Moderator
{
public class LogApplication
{
    public static void LogApplicationActivity(string IPAddress, string timestamp, string username, string activity, string urlcurrent, string referrerurl, string useragent)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {

            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd1.CommandText = "insert into LogApplication(IPAddress,TimeStamp,Username,Activity,URLCurrent,ReferrerURL,UserAgent) values (@IPAddress,@TimeStamp,@Username,@Activity,@URLCurrent,@ReferrerURL,@UserAgent)";
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPAddress", IPAddress);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", timestamp);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", activity);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URLCurrent", urlcurrent);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferrerURL", referrerurl);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserAgent", useragent);

                cmd1.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }


    }

    public static string RetrieveLatestLoggedinActivity(string username, string activity)
    {

        string value = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd1.CommandText = "select top 1 timestamp from LOGAPPLICATION where username=@Username and activity=@Activity order by timestamp desc ";
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", activity);
                cmd1.Connection = con;

                cmd1.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                if (cmd1.ExecuteScalar() != null)
                    value = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return value;
        // return dt;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Hurrah! Everything is a `string`. If you want a timestamp, then why is the `timestamp` parameter declared as `string` rather than as `DateTime`?

Comment: The error says line 43 because that's where it's being thrown. You need the stack trace to find out where it originated. In this example the reason is fairly obvious. There's a problem in your SQL stored procedure where it's got a value it can't turn into a datetime.

Comment: It is possible that you are passing C# datetime (`timestamp` parameter) in DMY format, however, for SQL server it is MDY by default. So it works sometimes when your datetime has `Day` <= 12 because that's valid even with MDY format. If you pass something like 20/10/2015, it will break as SQL will treat 20 as a month.

Comment: Why not parse the `Timestamp` column value as a Datetime instead of a string? (Look at the `DateTime.TryParse()` method)

Comment: @dotnetkid - the default depends on language settings. And, of course, when you say it works for datetimes <12, what you should really say is "works" - with the quotes - since it means the data will have been going in incorrectly, except on days when day = month.